# StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase() is returning wrong result

Tags: java, apache-stringutils

i have two values:

```
String a = "00tz"; // (Eclipse internal debug value: [, 0, 0, t, z]) and 
String b = "tz"; //   (Eclipse internal debug value: [, t, z])
```

I am reading this values from an ArrayList like

```
for (String a : stringLists) {
...
}
```

I get "false" when i compare this two values with `StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(a,b)`. But it should return true because "tz" is existing in "00tz".

Im using `apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`. To change the values a & b didn't worked. The length of "a" is 5 and "b" is 3. It also returns false when i use `a.contains(b)`.

These are the results when i output the value with

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

a:[-17, -69, -65, 48, 48, 118, 119]
b:[-17, -69, -65, 118, 119]
```

Im reading this values from a .txt file which contains several values like this. I read it in this way:

```
File fileA = new File("test/a.txt"); 

File fileB = new File("test/b.txt"); 

lista = (ArrayList<String>) FileUtils.readLines(fileA, "utf-8");

listb = (ArrayList<String>) FileUtils.readLines(fileB, "utf-8");
```

Do you have an idea what the problem is?

Thank you!

Comment: If you check the `.length` property of both, is the same as the amount of characters you can see?

Comment: Is `[, t, z]` supposed to be `[t, z]` or is it something like `[\0, t, z]` ?

Comment: I will give you a hint: Try `StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(b, a)`.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: You should mention which libraries you use. StringUtils could be apache or Spring or ...

Comment: Hi im using "apache.commons.lang3" library. To change the values a&b didnt work. The length of "a" is 5 and "b" is 3. It also returns false with a.contains(b)

Comment: Please tell use what `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));` and `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));` print and also where you read these Strings, since they obviously contain stuff which doesn't belong there.

Comment: import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String a = "00tz";
  String b = "tz";

  System.out.println(StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(b, a));
  System.out.println(StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(a, b));
 }

}
Output: false
true

Comment: @user3136131 OP already knows how this library works.

Comment: sorry didn;t see updates. maybe debugging the call of the method will help.

Comment: @Tom Hi! These are the results:
a: [-17, -69, -65, 48, 48, 118, 119]
b: [-17, -69, -65, 118, 119]

Im reading this values from a .txt file which contains several values like this. 
I read it in this way:
File fileA = new File("test/a.txt");

File fileB = new File("test/b.txt");

lista = (ArrayList) FileUtils.readLines(fileA, "utf-8");

listb = (ArrayList) FileUtils.readLines(fileB, "utf-8");

Comment: These bytes are the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). There are several questions here on StackOverflow to remove them (`-17`, `-69`, `-65` are the bytes for `\uFEFF`).

Comment: @Tom Hi it worked thank you. You can add it as answer.